# Trying to change default ubuntu storage to SD card

Tags: sd-card, chromebook

I recently modded a chromebook to run linux ubuntu 20.04 on its standard 16gb ssd. However, when the 16gb maximum is hit, the chromebook becomes stuck in a login loop, so I purchased a 550gb SD card. However, I've had heavy difficulties while trying to set it to the default storage location. I've also considered trying to install the OS on the SD card itself, but from what I'be read it seems that that will limit performance and may even lead to the card wearing out. I'm also a pretty big noob when it comes to Linux, can anyone help?

Comment: Could you buy a (larger) SSD, clone the old SSD to the new one, and then replace the old SSD with the new one? I imagine this wouldn't be too difficult if it is an M.2 NVME SSD, but I don't know much about Chromebooks.

Comment: I bet that would work but I already went out and bought the SD card, so I'd like to try and use that if possible, but it does make more sense in hindsight.

Comment: If you can boot to the SD card, it is probobly fine. Would I use SD cards in a NAS? Certainly not. But, it should work fine. After all, the Raspberry Pi uses a (micro) SD card as its boot medium, and they work fine. You won't get great performance, and _you should take backups_, but it should work. Are you trying to boot to the SD card, or just store stuff on it?

Comment: If you cannot boot off the SD card, then another option would be to use the SSD for the system and the SD for `/home` (and perhaps `/var`).

Comment: Whichever is easiest. I don't care what method I use to get the computer to store things on the card, but I've already tried moving my home folder to the card several times with no luck. I've been using this tutorial: https://www.howtogeek.com/442101/how-to-move-your-linux-home-directory-to-another-hard-drive/ with no success. It always gives me an error after editing fstab (specifically: a gvfs metadata error), I get stuck in a login loop, and have to reinstall the OS.

Comment: We were all noobs at one time. I have had similar problems with SD, SSD, and booting. Not easy to resolve, and can consume days of frustrations. Given the noob situation, I would recommend a backup and fresh install, but choosing carefully the partitions for efi, boot, root, home during the install process. A fresh install should require about 20 minutes, and should be successful. This was the most expedient course for me.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error (formatted as a code block) instead of putting it as a comment. Thanks!

Comment: I tried installing by making manual partitions for it and it all went well until the installer started "Creating ext4 file system for /home in partition #2 of SCSI4 (0,0,0) (sdc)... , after which it gave me the error `The attempt to mount a filesystem with type ext4 in SCSI4 (0,0,0) partition #2 (sdc) at /home failed`.

Comment: The most recent lines from the installer read. `/usr/lib/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:133: Warning: Source ID 15687` (and various other numbers) `was not found when attempting to remove it Glib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)` or the last bit will read, `Glib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)`. What should I do? –